# How to create a conditional sum in R?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, sum, mean

I am trying to calculate the sum for different columns in a data frame, based on different criteria.

This is my trial data: [image]

```
Year <- c(2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004)
COMP1 <- c(NA, 1, 2, 6, 9, NA, 2, 1, NA)  
COMP2 <- c(2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 4, > 1, 0, 1)   
COMP3 <- c(NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0)   
COMP4 <- c(25, 29, 16, 17, NA, 20, NA, 21, 12)

DF <- data.frame(Year, COMP1, COMP2, COMP3, COMP4)
```

So this is want I am trying to do:

For every year and every company (COMP), I want to calculate the sum of the values, BUT ONLY if the individual value in the cell is above the mean of values within that year).

I have achieved to calculate the sum and the mean, but I dont know how to combine them to create a sum with the condition mentioned.

These are the formulas I've tried so far (please note that my original sample has 6121 columns of different companies):

```
SUM <- aggregate(DF[, 2:6121], list(DF$Year), sum)

MEAN <- aggregate(DF[, 2:6121], list(DF$Year), mean)
```

Comment: When you provide sample data in R, it is really frustrating when your sample data is a _parsing error_. Please **try** the data you give us and make sure that it actually works. (`#NV` is not meaningful to R.)

Comment: @r2evans - thanks for your comment. I replaced the #NV to NA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  summarize(across(contains("COMP"), 
                   ~ sum(.x[.x > mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)], na.rm = TRUE)), 
            .by = Year)

# A tibble: 4 × 5
   Year COMP1 COMP2 COMP3 COMP4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2001     2     6     2    54
2  2002     9     6     4     0
3  2003     0     4     0     0
4  2004     0     1     1    21
```

Include values equals to and above the groups mean:

```
df %>%
  summarize(across(1:4, 
                   ~ sum(.x[.x >= mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)], na.rm = TRUE)), 
            .by = Year)

# A tibble: 4 × 5
   Year COMP1 COMP2 COMP3 COMP4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2001     2     6     2    54
2  2002     9     6     4    17
3  2003     2     4     0    20
4  2004     1     1     1    21
```

Comment: Thank you, @Chamkrai. I adjusted it a little bit to be independent from the "COMP".  So here is my final code:

DF %>%
  summarize(across(c(1:4), 
                   ~ sum(.x[which(.x > mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))], na.rm = TRUE)), 
            .by = Year)

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @Li4991 Yes, it was expected that you would do so! In `across()` you can use `1:4` and drop `c()`

Comment: I did notice that they count the values with "NA" as zero - or so it seems. In this way, e.g. for the year, in which there are only two values (one NA and one value), they don't count the value since it is below the mean. Is there a way to fix that? I would like to ignore the NA values and still calculate the mean of the rest of the values. In that case, the remaining value should still be counted. Do you have an idea @Chamkrai?

Comment: @Li4991 Simply replace `>` with `>=`, I have included an edit to illustrate this.

Answer (score 3):

## dplyr/tidyr

I think Chamkrai's answer is simplest for dplyr, but I tend to find working with data like to be more workable in a "long" format, so I'll keep this rendition. Look at the intermediate values (immediately after `pivot_longer`, then after `summarize` and before `pivot_wider`) to see what I mean.

```r
library(dplyr) # dplyr_1.1 or newer for `.by=`
library(tidyr)
quux %>%
  pivot_longer(-Year, names_to = "Comp") %>%
  summarize(
    res = sum(value[value > mean(value, na.rm=TRUE)], na.rm=TRUE),
    .by = c(Year, Comp)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Year, names_from = "Comp", values_from = "res")
# # A tibble: 4 × 5
#    Year COMP1 COMP2 COMP3 COMP4
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  2001     2     6     2    54
# 2  2002     9     6     4     0
# 3  2003     0     4     0     0
# 4  2004     0     1     1    21
```

## base R

```r
use <- lapply(quux[-1], function(y) {
  res <- y > ave(y, quux$Year, FUN = function(z) mean(z, na.rm = TRUE))
  !is.na(res) & res
})
use
# $COMP1
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# $COMP2
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# $COMP3
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# $COMP4
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

With `use` we can adjust the values in `quux` so that those values that are not above the mean are zeroed out:

```r
quux[-1] * use
#   COMP1 COMP2 COMP3 COMP4
# 1    NA     0    NA    25
# 2     0     3     0    29
# 3     2     3     2     0
# 4     0     0     0     0
# 5     9     6     4    NA
# 6    NA     4     0     0
# 7     0     0     0    NA
# 8     0     0     1    21
# 9    NA     1     0     0
```

Now we can use `aggregate` on that:

```r
aggregate(quux[-1] * use, quux["Year"], FUN = function(z) sum(z, na.rm = TRUE))
#   Year COMP1 COMP2 COMP3 COMP4
# 1 2001     2     6     2    54
# 2 2002     9     6     4     0
# 3 2003     0     4     0     0
# 4 2004     0     1     1    21
```

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(quux)[, lapply(.SD, function(z) sum(z[z > mean(z, na.rm = TRUE)], na.rm = TRUE)),
                      by = Year]
#     Year COMP1 COMP2 COMP3 COMP4
#    <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
# 1:  2001     2     6     2    54
# 2:  2002     9     6     4     0
# 3:  2003     0     4     0     0
# 4:  2004     0     1     1    21
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(Year = c(2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004), COMP1 = c(NA, 1, 2, 6, 9, NA, 2, 1, NA), COMP2 = c(2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 4, 1, 0, 1), COMP3 = c(NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0), COMP4 = c(25, 29, 16, 17, NA, 20, NA, 21, 12)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

DF <- data.table(Year, COMP1, COMP2, COMP3, COMP4)

conditinalSum <- function(x){
  x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  sum(x[x > mean(x)])
}

DF[, lapply(.SD, conditinalSum), by = Year]
```

Comment: (Don't think I copied your code into my answer, I was mid-edit when your answer appeared. :-)